# Find and edit favicon in Firefox places.sqlite

Tags: sqlite, firefox, favicon

I recently added a new favicon to a site of mine but it will not update in my Firefox bookmarks to show the new favicon (the old icon remains).
I have asked for help on Mozilla Support but haven't had a fix- see [Mozilla Support](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/993818?esab=a&s=&r=0&as=s)

I have tried many things eg deleting the bookmark and re-bookmarking and trying 'forget history' (even resetting Firefox to default) with no success.

Now I am using SQLITE manager addon to try and edit bookmark favicon from places.sqlite but I cannot access the url for this bookmark! The bookmark is in a folder but in Sqlite manager I see the folder but cannot open it to find the url bookmark!

As ever I am most grateful for helpful replies to fix this bookmark favicon problem-thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I still do not know how to edit the firefox places.sqlite file but I fixed the favicon problem with this (see my link to Mozilla Support above):

> You can try to let all favicons expire with pasting this code in the command line in the Browser Console (Firefox/Tools > Web Developer).

```
https://developer.mozilla.org/Tools/Browser_Console
```

Note that this will remove all favicons, so you need to revisit website to make Firefox retrieve the favicons.

var fS = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/browser/favicon-service;1"]
         .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIFaviconService);
fS.expireAllFavicons();

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the [Places](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/Places) SQLite database, though when Firefox is using it (close Firefox and then you can edit the file with your favorite SQLite editor).  See also [Places](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Places) on the Mozilla Wiki.

The [Mozillazine places.sqlite](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Places.sqlite) page mentions the [SQLite manager add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/5817).  In order to use this add-on to edit your active profile's history, you'll have to copy places.sqlite and edit the copy.  When you're done editing, close Firefox and copy the modified version atop the original.